# Table Personalization appears not complete, I get only the columns without sort, filter and groups

Tags: sapui5

I try to create Table Personalization the same like in this link , see it please first [Table Personalization](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.tutorial.smartControls/sample/sap.ui.comp.tutorial.smartControls.06) but I get as you can see in this photo , only columns, there are no sort, no filter, no groups.Maybe someone can help. I will be glad for some solutions...............

Thank you

Mahmood[image]

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.volkswagen.ifdb.cc.sopraempApplication.controller.Overview" height="100%" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" xmlns:svm="sap.ui.comp.smartvariants"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar">
<App id="app">
    <f:DynamicPage id="page" headerExpanded="{/headerExpanded}">
        <f:title>
            <f:DynamicPageTitle>
                <f:heading>
                    <svm:SmartVariantManagement id="svm" showExecuteOnSelection="true"/>
                </f:heading>
                <f:expandedContent>
                    <Label id="expandedLabel" text="No filters active"/>
                </f:expandedContent>
                <f:snappedContent>
                    <Label id="snappedLabel" text="No filters active"/>
                </f:snappedContent>
            </f:DynamicPageTitle>
        </f:title>
        <f:header>
            <f:DynamicPageHeader>
                <f:content>
                    <fb:FilterBar id="filterbar" persistencyKey="myPersKey" useToolbar="false" search=".onSearch" filterChange=".onFilterChange"
                        afterVariantLoad=".onAfterVariantLoad">
                        <fb:filterGroupItems>
                            <fb:FilterGroupItem name="Name" label="Name" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                <fb:control>
                                    <MultiComboBox name="Name" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductNames', templateShareable: true }">
                                        <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                    </MultiComboBox>
                                </fb:control>
                            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                            <fb:FilterGroupItem name="Category" label="Category" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                <fb:control>
                                    <MultiComboBox name="Category" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductCategories', templateShareable: true }">
                                        <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                    </MultiComboBox>
                                </fb:control>
                            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                            <fb:FilterGroupItem name="SupplierName" label="SupplierName" groupName="Group1" visibleInFilterBar="true">
                                <fb:control>
                                    <MultiComboBox name="SupplierName" selectionChange=".onSelectionChange" items="{ path: '/ProductSuppliers', templateShareable: true }">
                                        <core:Item key="{key}" text="{name}"/>
                                    </MultiComboBox>
                                </fb:control>
                            </fb:FilterGroupItem>
                        </fb:filterGroupItems>
                    </fb:FilterBar>
                </f:content>
            </f:DynamicPageHeader>
        </f:header>
        <f:content >
            <smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="ResponsiveTable" editable="false"
                entitySet="Products" useVariantManagement="false" useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Products" showRowCount="true"
                useExportToExcel="false" enableAutoBinding="true" enableAutoColumnWidth="true">
                
                <smartTable:customToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onCreate"/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://copy" press="onCopyPress" enabled="{= ${smartTable>/tableBinding/length} > 0}"/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://paste" press="onPastePress" enabled="{= ${clipboard>/itemData} !== undefined}"/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onRemoveRowsUi"/>
    </Toolbar>
</smartTable:customToolbar>
                <Table id="table" inset="false" items="{path: '/ProductCollection'}" itemPress="onPress">
                    <!--<headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar >
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onCreate"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://copy" press="onCopyPress" enabled="{= ${table>/items}.length > 0}"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://paste" press="onPastePress" enabled="{= ${clipboard>/itemData} !== undefined}"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onRemoveRowsUi"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>-->
                    <columns>
                        <Column width="5em">
                            <CheckBox select="selectAll"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column >
                            <Text text="Name"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Category"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="SupplierName"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Status"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="DateOfProduction"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Price"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items >
                        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation">
                            <cells >
                                <CheckBox id="ch1" select="checkDone"/>
                                <!--    <RadioButton id="selected" text="" selected="true"/>-->
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}"/>
                                <Text text="{Category}"/>
                                <Text text="{SupplierName}"/>
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Status}" text="{Quantity}"/>
                                <Text text="{DateOfProduction}"/>
                                <ObjectNumber number="{Price}" unit="{CurrencyCode}"/>
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
            </smartTable:SmartTable>
        </f:content>
    </f:DynamicPage>
```

</mvc:View>